# Is it possible to access more than 4GB of RAM in unreal mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, osdev, memory-segmentation

On an x86-64 CPU, is it possible to switch to unreal mode and be able to use more than 32 bits to address memory?

Usually, the CPU (80386 or later, 286 needs `loadall` since it can't return to real mode without resetting and trashing all registers) can be put in unreal mode by first entering protected mode, setting up a GDT (Global Descriptor Table) entry with base 0, limit 0xFFFFF and granularity set. When loading a segment register with the appropriate selector, the segment descriptor cache stores the data in the GDT entry and persists even when switching back to real mode, allowing to access the full 4GB range using something like `DS:[EBX]`. The only caveat is that it won't work well for the code segment, because interrupts change `CS` and destroy the upper half of `EIP`.

I know that segmentation is disabled in 64-bit long mode, so it is impossible to set up a GDT that has 64-bit segment limits. However, using MSRs (Model Specific Registers) it is possible to set the `FS` and `GS` 64-bit base address. When switching back to real mode, does this setting persist so that addresses higher than 0xFFFFFFFF can be accessed using `FS` and `GS`? Or maybe there is another entirely different way to do this?

Comment: Interesting question! In compatibility mode the high 32 bits of the base are disregarded, I assume this also happens in PM (and thus also in RM). For this to work the MSRs must read/write into the shadow registers (that would have to be updated to hold 64-bit bases even though the GDT cannot and segmentation is not used). It is also equally possible that the bases of `fs` and `gs` are just handled specially only in 64-bit mode, leaving the MSRs out of the game when in PM (and thus in RM).
In either case it seems not possible to use `IA32_FS/GS_BASE` in RM, but it's worth testing!

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought pure 32-bit legacy/protected mode OSes could and did still use the MSRs to set FS and/or GS base to more efficiently implement thread-local storage without having to actually mess around with an LDT.  OTOH, [`wrfsbase`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrfsbase:wrgsbase) is listed as invalid in 32-bit mode, only valid in 64-bit long mode.  And even Linux's `arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, unsigned long)` is only available in 64-bit mode, not 32.  So I guess 32-bit code uses something else to config TLS.

Comment: re: interrupts: yeah apparently "huge unreal mode" with a 4GB range for CS is pretty much impractical for that reason.  "big unreal mode" (where you only use flat data access, and a 64k code segment) is much more robust: https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode

Comment: Another probably-incorrect argument against this: the "address size" is still 32-bit for `[fs: edi]`.  But the "address size" is just the size of the offset, not necessarily the size of the linear address.  Of course paging can only handle 32-bit virtual addresses so in *that* case address calculations truncate to 32-bit, so it's reasonable to guess that the HW for segment-base + offset does just truncate to 32-bit outside long mode.  But it's plausible for unreal mode, or protected mode with paging disabled, to allow this workaround.

Comment: But IDK why it would be different from a DS base of 3GB (configured normally via GDT) with an address like `[ds: 0xff000000]` in protected mode with paging disabled.  Does that allow access to nearly 8GB in protected mode?  (probably no, but again plausible.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Testing in Bochs, in PM, the addresses are truncated to 32 bits. But I made I note to make a proper test with real hardware :)

Comment: The upper 32-bits of FS/GS.base are ignored in compatibility mode and it's not possible form a linear address greater than 4G, so presumably this would also apply to real mode or protected mode.

Comment: Sorry i can understand your question. do you mean read a 64bits address data in protect mode and a 64bits cpu? it's impossible... but PSE-36 mode can make cpu read up to 36bits address

Comment: @AlanCui  You can't use PSE-36 in unreal mode though.  You could use it Virtual 8086 mode to give a real mode program access to physical address greater than 4GB, though it would still be limited to 4GB of virtual address space so you'd need to use some sort of bank switching to access more than 4GB of RAM.